# Searching throw a twig in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, search, twig

I have a view which i included a *search form* , i want when user enter *some words* , I retrieve datas from *database* and show them into new view page:

**Search Form :**

```
 <!-- Search Form -->
          <form class="pull-right hidden" role="search" id="nav-search-form" method="post" action="{{ path('search_route') }}">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name ="search">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Routing:

```
search_route:
    path:  /results
    defaults: { _controller: MyAppDataBundle:Default:search }
```

**My action in DefaultController :**

```
 public function searchAction()
    {
         $request  = $this->getRequest();
         $data= $request->request->all();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
         'SELECT p.name , p.description 
         FROM MyAppDataBundle:MyTable p
        WHERE p.name LIKE data'
        )->setParameter('data',$data['search']);

        $res = $query->getResult();

        return $this->render('MyAppDataBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
            'res' => $res));
    }
```

I have this **Error** :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 117: Error: Expected '.' or '(', got 'data'
```

Comment: Just change `data` in your SQL statement to `:data`

Comment: yes this is the solution , it should be  :data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your query you are not defining the parameter like `?` or `:data`

```
  WHERE p.name LIKE data
```

it should be

```
  WHERE p.name LIKE :data
```

[**See Symfony topic Databases and Doctrine**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)